# Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, database, asp-classic, hosting

I've been developing a ASP website that uses a database. It works offline when I'm testing it but as soon as I upload it to my fasthosts account I get the following error when trying to run it:

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

The connection string is as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:ThreadString %>" ProviderName="<%$     
ConnectionStrings:ThreadString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Thread] 
WHERE ([rank] &lt;= ?) ORDER BY [rank]">
```

web.config file:

```
<add name="ThreadString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data  
Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb"  providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set the IIS process to allow 32-bit programs?

Comment: Sorry.. I'm pretty new to this. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection to an ACCDB file (Access 2007 format) requires the ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver. 
This driver needs to be installed on the ISP machine.
(That's probably the reason they ask you a different plan)

However you could change the format of your file to be Access 2003 that use the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` and this driver doesn't need to be installed on the ISP machine.

This is a document on the Microsoft site that explain how to do it.
[Save an Access 2010 database in an earlier file format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/save-an-access-2010-database-in-an-earlier-file-format-HA010341553.aspx)

But there is another problem. This driver is 32 bit only, so your ISP should allow the 32bit driver to run in the hosting process of your site (if they use a 64 bit OS). How this is done depends on your ISP tools and interface and how much they let you personalize their services.

Usually on a local IIS server you follow these steps

- Go to the IIS Manager
- Right click on the DefaultAppPool (or your application pool)
- Select Advanced Settings
- Set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to True.

Comment: very informative, thank you. I changed the driver but now im getting a new error Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unrecognized database format '[file location]'. I made the database in access 2010

Comment: Did you change the format of your ACCDB file to MDB as explained in the link above?. Rename also the file to have an MDB extension (Access 2003)

Comment: 8 hours I spent on that error. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I dont have enough points to upvote but I'll accept the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps

1. Right click on application and select properties.
2. Go to Build section.
3. Select Platform target to Any CPU
4. Save the application.

build and run.

Comment: the project platform is already targeted to any CPU

Comment: which database you are using excel or Access ???

Comment: access. The hosting company led me to believe that I need to take a separate database hosting service. Is that true?

Comment: It is necessary for sql databse, but I don't think so for access database. And try provider with  Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;

Comment: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: that was trying to run it locally. I'm just uploading to server just now

Comment: Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;

Comment: Unrecognized database format 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\SPOASP\App_Data\Database.accdb'.

Comment: yeah its still got the same error online